# How to set a contact's number in an auto complete textview in android?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-contentprovider

I have a code from where I can get the contacts name in a auto complete text view, here is my code

```
autoContacts=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.actvContacts);
          Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            startManagingCursor(emailCursor);
            autoContacts.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailCursor, new String[] {Email.DATA1}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}));
            autoContacts.setThreshold(0);
```

but when I click in one of the name then it sets a text in that Autocomplete textview like this:

```
android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@44efc9c8
```

but here I want to set the specific phone number on that, how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the setCursorToStringConverter

> Sets the converter used to convert the filtering Cursor into a String.
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html

In your case you could do something like this:

```
String[] from = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
};
autoContacts=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(emailCursor);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailCursor, from, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}); 
adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {              
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            final int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            final String str = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            return str;
        }
});
autoContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
autoContacts.setThreshold(0);
```

Comment: @Nirupoma Saha Chaiti Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask – Filipe Batista